# Can i send many builds to play store and app store?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am creating my first mobile app and i had to resize my app, and i was wondering if i could just send many builds to both stores with different resolutions sizes to fit in different smarthphones, is that possible?

Comment: If you set up the right sizes in the assets for the iOS app, the app store do the resizing for different downloaders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any idea for apple app store, but while developing your android app, there's something called layout qualifiers that can contain different screen designs for various screen sizes. So the answer is no, but during development you can incorporate this functionality when designing app screens.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You send only one build.

In iOS development, Apple have thought of this :)

Xcode "understands" different screen sizes, and there is a whole system for handling different screen sizes/type. You will have to learn about it.

Comment: Actually Google have thought (or copied iOS) of this with [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) which is now enforced as a format when uploading to play store. You pretty much upload your apps compiled code and resources then play store is responsible for building and serving APKs that include only resources relevant for specific device configurations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as concern in play store you can publish many application but with different package name. Every application has different package name.

For different resolution handling android gives the qualifiers to handle the same.

Have a look [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)